# How to grey out text unless checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, checkbox

Hi I am new to android coding and I am trying to code a battery saver app. I want certain text and time selections to be greyed out and disabled unless the `Disable data overnight` checkbox is checked. Please help this poor noob! I looked at other posts but I don't understand them. Thanks!

```
<script android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

function setfunction(@+id/checkBox2) {
var el = document.getElementById("data_off_night");
if(el.checked)
  document.getElementById("data_off_night").disabled = false;
else
 document.getElementById("data_off_night").disabled = true;    
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be it will help you.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        checkBox.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        checkBox.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: It keeps saying unexpected text. I am really new to this and I dont exactly know what to replace and put in with @+id/checkBox2 or @+id/checkBox1